# How to put text after the input field in python?

Tags: python, input

In python if I wanted to have someone enter a loan amount in dollars, I could code something like this:

```
# Loan amount
L = float(input("Enter the loan amount: $"))
```

But what if I want, let's say the interest rate, which is a percentage. If I coded:

```
# Interest rate
I = float(input("Enter the interest rate: "))
```

How could I get the percentage sign, %, to show up after what they input?

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you trying to strip the "%"? Its typically not used in calculations themselves. And since its just a way of expressing fractions of a hundred, `I = float(input("Enter the interest rate: "))/100.` would do.

Comment: I think Garrett is looking to have the console produce: "Enter interest rate: 10%". With dollars it works because the dollar sign comes before the number. With percentages however, it comes after, and input prints a newline after the input.

Comment: I guess you could do something with the `curses` module, but I have no experience with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is controlling the terminal's cursor.

After user giving input and hit enter, cursor moves to next line.

You need to move the cursor up one line then move it to end of that line, print % then move cursor back to the new line.

You can do that using Terminal's escape sequence.

This library can make it easier for you to perform cursor movement

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/475116-using-terminfo-for-portable-color-output-cursor-co/